# webapp-container paste password?

Tags: webapps

I created a few shortcuts to some web-apps using `webapp-container`. For example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=KodiRemote
Comment=Kodi Remote
Type=Application
Icon=/1TB/Seafile/icons/kodi.png
Exec=webapp-container --maximized --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https?://192.168.1.161:8297/* http://192.168.1.161:8297
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

The problem is that some of the apps require a long complicated password and I cannot do copy and paste. crl+v does not work and click click only gives me the copy option. Is there a solution to this other than typing the password by hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+V is possible in the latest Ubuntu Web Browser oxide-qt 1.8, not yet included into Ubuntu but you can use the phablet ppa: https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: It is included in 15.04 *oxide-qt Version: 1.8.4*